# Can we use 'var' in this scenario

Tags: c#

Can we use var twice in the function.
e.g

```
var varname= sometype;
if(true)
{
    varname= type1;
}
else
{
   varname=type2;
}
```

If this is not possible I would say this is a limitation of var.

Comment: you haven't used the var keyword twice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well that's only using `var` itself a single time - but so long as you have an expression to initialize it with, it's fine. (`type1` and `type2` will need to be convertible to the type of `sometype` though.)

What you *can't* do is this:

```
var x; // No initialization expression
if (condition)
{
    x = firstExpression;
}
else
{
    x = secondExpression;
}
```

There *has* to be an initialization expression (which can't be an anonymous function or the null literal). If you want this sort of thing, you could potentially use the conditional operator:

```
var x = condition ? firstExpression : secondExpression;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `var` in this instance, but only `sometype` is of the same type as `type1` and `type2`.

If `type1` and `type2` are in fact different types, you can still use `var` if and only if `sometype` is a superclass of both `type1` and `type2`.

If you don't know at compile time what `type1` and `type2` are, you will need to use `dynamic` instead of `var`.  If you DO know that both `type1` and `type2` implement the same interface, use the interface in the declaration instead of `var`.

Answer (score 1):

The in-line assignment will define the type of `var`; if the `type1` and `type2` are compatible with `sometype` that'll work, but the first assignment is pointless. You could perhaps cast a `null` if it is a ref-type; this will essentially a no-op:

```
var varname= (sometype)null;
```

But by that point, you might as well just use no assignment:

```
sometype varname;
```

Arguably a better layout would be

```
var name = condition ? expr1 : expr2;
```

Note that if there isn't an obvious same type (perhaps they are different subclasses of a common base-type), you may need to help it decide:

```
var name = condition ? (Foo)expr1 : expr2;
```

If the types are unrelated, this is not an appropriate use of `var`; you may find `object` or `dynamic` more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is confusing. You don't assign types to variables, you assign values. If you say `var varname=3;` then `varname` is an `int`. You are then constrained to only assign ints (and values that convert to ints) to it, just as if you had said `int varname=3;`- there's no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. `var` is typesafe, meaning its type will be inferred from the assignment. So in your example, the `var` is of type sometype. Assigning a different type to it will not be possible (as long as there is no conversion possible between them).

Using `object` instead of `var` will work in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible as long as you have initialization syntax in place. Additionally, it is good practice to use var for reference types and type for value types

Answer (score 0):

The var type in C# requires initialization to a type. That type is determined and enforced at compile time. When the compiler determines that the type will vary, it will give it an anonymous type (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx).

The anonymous type can only be cast to an object type. So the short answer is no, you cannot use a var to refer to more than one type. Even object which can contain various types is itself a type and a var that is given that type cannot be changed to another. In this sense the var keyword allows you to be flexible and yet still strongly typed.

If you have an array of items of various types, the compiler implement the anon type to the var and it will essentially act as an object. A decent explanation can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx.